# Download .rcproject from remote and place it in AR view?

Tags: ios, arkit, reality-composer

So, I'm following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_3d_content_with_reality_composer) and created a composition with Reality Composer. There is a step in the docs called **Add the Composition to Your App**, what I would like is to add the Composition to my app dynamically. Upload the file to a server and download it from a URL.
In the tutorial, it says that when importing the `.rcproject` it generates a code

> Xcode automatically generates code that you use to manipulate the stored objects. For example, Xcode generates a class for the scene based on the scene’s name (MyGreatScene) inside an enumeration based on the name of the project file (MyProject.rcproject). As a convenience, it also provides a loadMyGreatScene() method

Is there a way for me to generate this code downloading it from my url? Should I upload another file to be able to download it?